# python requests.get() keep getting 401

Tags: python, http, web, ipython, python-requests

The task I want to complete is very simple. To do a http get request using python. 
Below is the code I used:

```
url = 'http://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/AjaxWarehouseBrowseLookupView?storeId=11301&catalogId=11701&langId=-1&parentGeoNode=10112'

requests.get(url)
```

Then I got:

```
<Response [401]>
```

I am new to python, can someone help? Thanks!

**Update:**
Based on the comments. It seems the code is okay, but I do get the 401 response. I doubt my company's network has some restrictions? But I can access and get a valid response through a browser. Is there a way to bypass my company's firewall/proxy or whatever? Just to pretend that I am using a browser in python? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't. I get a 200. Apparently that website doesn't like you, have you tried to access their servers a lot lately?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I found this web site today and only tried a few times. If you guys can access, that means the code is OK. Is it possible that my company's network has some restrictions? If so, how can I by pass that? I can access that URL through a browser.

Comment: If your browser can access the page, then you very likely have a proxy established. You would need to know those settings and [set them in the code](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, I think that is the issue. But how can I find the proxy settings?

Comment: It may be enforced on the network level so that you will be unable to change (or find) it easily on your own computer.

Comment: @cricket_007 haha, found it, in case others also have similar problem. Below is the command I used to find the proxy setting: reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "autoConfigUrl

Comment: You can provide that as an answer to your own question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser is accessing the web via a proxy server, look that up on your browser settings and use that in python.

r = requests.get(url, 
                 proxies={"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"})

your proxy server will have a different address.

Comment: It seems the right way to go! But how can I find the proxy setting? I never set that for my browser...